# How to stop HAProxy from stripping auth header

Tags: authentication, header, haproxy

So I'm having an issue with HAProxy stripping the authorization header from from my call when redirecting to a separate URL. Specifically, I want to hit an AWS lambda, based on the URL path.

subdomain.domain/mo/api should be routed to the lambda, and it is based on this configuration, but I receive this response back from the lambda (using postman):

{
  "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}

hitting the lambda url (bypassing HAProxy) works as expected, all headers are exactly the same.

Proxy config:

```
global

    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    maxconn 20000
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3 no-tls-tickets
    ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
    ssl-default-server-options no-sslv3 no-tls-tickets

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    option forwardfor
    monitor-uri /index.html
    stats enable
    stats uri /stats
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http
  bind *:80
#Defining ACL based on a string in URI
  acl dm_in_uri path_sub dm
  acl mo_in_uri path_sub mo
  acl lab_host hdr(host) -i subdomain.domain.com
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
#Special route which matches both hostname and string acl
  use_backend lab_mo_api if lab_host mo_in_uri api_in_uri
  use_backend lab_portal if lab_host

frontend https
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/<blah>.pem
#Defining ACL based on a string in URI
  acl api_in_uri path_sub api
  acl dm_in_uri path_sub dm
  acl mo_in_uri path_sub mo
  acl lab_host hdr(host) -i subdomain.domain.com
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
#Special route which matches both hostname and string acl 
  use_backend lab_mo_api if lab_host mo_in_uri api_in_uri
  use_backend lab_portal if lab_host


backend lab_mo_api
  reqrep (.*)\/mo\/api(\/.*) \1\ /lab\/
  redirect prefix https://<aws_lambda_url> code 301
```

Comment: It is my solemn missing to find out that missing configuration key @SeanL. I will stop at nothing to scour the internet and come back to this very location with your answer _poste haste_.

Comment: So, I have fixed my problem with a reboot. I apologise that this does not solve your problem as well -- but I can assure you that HAProxy does *not* drop `Authorization` headers, and that this auth issue is more than likely behind your HAProxy!